# Kusama 1.2 - How to associate stash accounts with host via RPC/JS/shell

Tags: polkadot-js, kusama, polkadot-sdk

This key previously worked with Kusama until the recent metadata update (with BEEFY key)

```js
const keys = await api.query.session.nextKeys(address.address);
const keysHex = keys.toHex();
const result = await api.rpc.author.hasSessionKeys(keysHex);
const normalizedResult = result.toPrimitive();
```

But now this always returns `false` for Kusama (still works for chain Polkadot). If I check specific subkeys with `hasKeys` (like the new BEEFY), it returns `true`. What do I need to change for this to work with the new version of Polkadot SDK?